# How to get UTC date/time from a date/time string that contains timezone offset in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, offset, utc

Given a string like this: 
    '2015-11-23T07:00:10.563-04:00'
I am trying to determine the UTC date/time which I would expect to be:
    '2015-11-23 11:00:10.5630000'

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT sys_extract_utc(
        to_timestamp_tz('2015-11-23T07:00:10.563-04:00', 
                        'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.FF TZH:TZM')
         )  
FROM DUAL;
```

but this produces the result:

```
2015/11/23 03:00:10.563000000
```

Even when I change the timezone offset to positive, I get the same result. I must be misunderstanding something so would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no space between fractional seconds and timezone hour. So remove space from you pattern, and it'll give desired result.

```
SQL> SELECT sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp_tz('2015-11-23T07:00:10.563-04:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.FFTZH:TZM'))  
FROM DUAL; 

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2015-11-23T07:00:10.563-04:00','YYYY-MM-DD
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
23-NOV-15 11.00.10.563000000 AM
```

Comment: Just figured it as you posted - was pulling my hair out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - the space character between ".....hh24:mi:ss.FF TZH:TZM" was causing the problem.

This now works perfectly:

```
SELECT sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp_tz('2015-11-23T07:00:10.563+04:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.FFTZH:TZM'))  FROM DUAL;
```